# Gamma function in shaders

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, hlsl, lighting

Using spherical harmonics for lighting I faced a problem for a big enough bandwidths. The correctness of an approximation by first `n^2` terms became worse and worse starting from `n=7`. I look into associated Legendre polynomials definition and found out, that there is a ratio of factorials `(l - m)! / (l + m)!` in normalization constant. For `n = 7` `(l + m)!` can be up to `12!`. I have to use `float` (IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point type), due to GPUs nature.

Now I think, that [`tgamma`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/tgamma) from `C`/`C++` might be more appropriate, then naive calculation of factorial by definition. Even more: maybe there is a good (approximation) formula for ratio of [gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (of two big arguments).

Is there a good stable approach to calculate gamma function (for big positive integers) in shaders?

Surely I just can save a lookup table (matrix) for all the possible combinations of values in numerator and denominator, but I want to have alternative (space-efficient) approach.

Comment: Just for clarification, because this question touches graphics *and* calculus. OP is asking about availability of the generalized factorial function called "[Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)". OP is not asking about colour space gamma factor correction.

Comment: @datenwolf Good point. It is sad, but most relevant search results touches upon gamma correction.

Comment: You don't need `(a+m)!` but  `(a-m)!/(a+m)!`right? Then `(a-m)!/(a+m)!` = `1/(a+m)/(a+m-1)/(a+m-2).../(a-m+1)`

Comment: where do I go if I am asking about the colour space gamma factor correction function definitions :)?